# Jackson Nested Map Deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization, fasterxml

I've to handle a complex `initial.json` that looks like this:

```
{
  "id": "ID123",
  "mapJobProfiles": {
    "23": {
      "Cineca": {
        "large": {
          "cm": 8,
          "cr": 8,
          "mavg": 8.235,
          "mmax": 17.541,
          "nm": 65,
          "nr": 5,
          "ravg": 0.297,
          "rmax": 0.499,
          "sh1max": 0,
          "shtypmax": 20.141,
          "shtypavg": 14.721
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Its class has 2 attributes:

```
private String id;
private JobProfilesMap mapJobProfiles;
```

JobProfilesMap is a POJOs that have a single attribute: 
 `Map<String,Map<String, Map<String, JobProfile>>> mapJobProfile`

I've an addition constraint, I've to avoid having "mapJobProfile" as property name for JobProfilesMap().
To achieve this, since annotation @jsonunwrapped doesn't work for Map, I've added to JobProfilesMap:

```
`@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, JobProfile>>> getMapJobProfile(){
    return mapJobProfile;
}`
```

(that correctly works by testing only JobProfilesMap deserialization)

But I get

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "23" ... 
not marked as ignorable (one known property: "mapJobProfile"])
```

if I try to deserialize `initial.json`.

Since jackson correctly handles whole `initial.json`'s deserialization if I don't remove "mapJobProfile" property name, is it possibile to achieve the same result removing the property and without adding a custom deserializer?

Comment: Why is mapJobProfiles not simply a Map<String, JobProfile>?

Comment: See it as an additional constraint ;)
(The .json I've pasted is only a quick view, to improve readability I've only written a small part  )